# Using npgsql in a class

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I've been using npgsql for a few years now.

I've never had an issue until recently when the load on my PostgreSQL server increased dramatically.

At the moment I have hundreds of instances of postgres.exe "Running" and "Terminating" on my server every second.

When I switch on pooling, it doesn't make a difference to the amount of instances being created / terminated and after a few minutes I get an error:

```
The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds)
```

I'm now questioning if my method of using npgsql is correct.

I used nuget to add npgsql into my project and created the following class which is used every time that I run a query:

```
Public Class dlNpgSQL
    Dim _sqlCommand As NpgsqlCommand
    Dim _sqlDataAdapter As NpgsqlDataAdapter
    Dim _dataset As DataSet

    Public Sub New()
        _sqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.                      
                         ConnectionStrings("connstring").ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDataSet(ByVal strQuery As String) As DataSet
        _dataset = New DataSet
        _sqlDataAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(strQuery, OpenConnection)
        _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataset)
        Return _dataset
    End Function

    Public Function OpenConnection() As NpgsqlConnection
        If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
           _sqlConnection.Open()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub CloseConnection()
       If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            _sqlConnection.Close()
       End If
    End Function
End Class
```

I run queries as following:

```
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim objDB As New dlNpgSQL("connstring")
tmpSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1"
Try
    ds = objDB.GetDataSet(tmpSQL)
Catch ex As Exception
    If (objDB IsNot Nothing) Then
        objDB.CloseConnection()
    End If
    Return Nothing
Finally
    If (objDB IsNot Nothing) Then
        objDB.CloseConnection()
    End If
End Try
```

The connection string I use is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name = "connstring" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=password;Database=test_db;CommandTimeout=600;Pooling=True;"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I using npgsql in the correct way?
2. If so, why are so many instances of postgres.exe being created?
3. Why do I get the error about the pool being exhausted?
4. Is there a way to see what connections are in the pool? When I check pg_stat_activity, there are no open connections.

I've been battling with this for days - any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that you can see instances of postgres.exe, and at the same time pg_stat_activity is empty? That would be very surprising...

Comment: Your wrapper contains some bad coding practices, although it isn't obvious from the above sample how that would lead to the error. Specifically, if `CloseConnection()` is called but the connection is in anything but the Open state, nothing happens. This suggests that if the connection is currently busy, or possibly broken, `Close()` is never called on it, which would mean a connection leak. If you call `CloseConnection()` only when the connection is open, then there's no reason to have the wrapper in the first place - just call `Close()` directly on the connection.

Comment: To summarize, I'd seriously consider getting rid of your wrapper, and taking advantage of Visual Basic's `Using` statement to ensure that the connection *always* gets disposed.

Comment: Finally, to understand exactly what's going on, please post a complete, minimal code sample which demonstrates the problem, rather than the isolated code samples above.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, thanks for the assistance. What I mean by not showing in pg_stat_activity is that I see connections opening and closing however none that stay open. I assumed with pooling the connections would remind open for a while. I'll update the code to close the connection for any state. Can you point me to any code examples for the best practices on using npgsql? I'm not sure what code example to post. Do you want a function where I query the database? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't have any specific VB code samples, but any generic database coffee the uses `Using` should be fine. Try writing a minimal, self-contained console app that reproduces the issue - this will help you understand where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks for the advice!